# Circuits in a matroid

Tags: graph-theory

"A minimal (inclusionwise) dependent set in a matroid is called a circuit."

If I have set I which is independent, how does extending I by I + x create a circuit? The way I'm thinking about it, if the set is independent then extending it by one element would at most create a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying set of a graphic matroid $M(G)$ is the set $E$ of edges of the (multi)graph $G$; a set $I\subseteq E$ is independent if and only if it is a forest, i.e., if and only if it does not contain a cycle. A set $C\subseteq E$ is a circuit if and only if it is a minimal dependent set of edges: it does contain a cycle, but removing any one edge from $C$ leaves an independent set, one that contains no cycle. Such a set of edges must form a cycle, so the circuits of $M(G)$ are the edges sets of the cycles of the graph $G$.

This means that adding another edge to an independent set $I$ may or may not give you a circuit: it depends both on $I$ and on the edge that you add. Let $G$ be the following graph, in which I’ve numbered the edges for easy reference:

```
                 1     2  
              a-----b-----c  
             3|    4|    5|  
              d-----e-----f  
                 6     7
```

The set $I_1=\{1,2,6\}$ of edges does not contain a cycle, so it’s an independent set, and you can easily check that if you add any one of the remaining edges $3,4,5$, or $7$ to $I_1$, you still have a forest and hence an independent set.

The set $I_2=\{1,3,6\}$ of edges is also acyclic and hence independent, but if we add edge $4$, we get a $4$-cycle; this is a circuit in the matroid, since removing any one of its four edges leaves a tree (in fact a path) and hence an independent set. On the other hand, we can add edge $2$ to get $\{1,2,3,6\}$ without creating a cycle: $\{1,2,3,6\}$ is still an independent set.

The set $I_3=\{1,2,3,5,6\}$ of edges is another independent set, but this time adding either of the remaining edges, $4$ or $7$, results in an edge set that contains a cycle: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ contains the cycle $\{1,4,6,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$ *is* (the edge set of) a cycle. Thus, $I_3$ is a maximal independent set, i.e., a base. Nevertheless, only one of the two dependent sets $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$ produced by adding a single edge is a circuit: $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$ is a circuit, because removing any single edge leaves an independent set, but $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is not, because we can remove edge $2$ to get $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$, which still contains the cycle $\{1,4,6,3\}$.