# Constructing a basis for a matroid with a circuit in it.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, graphic-matroids

Here is the question I am trying to solve (Matroid Theory, second edition by Martin Oxley, Chapter 1, section 2):

Prove that if $C$ is a circuit of a matroid $M$ and $e \in C,$ then $M$ has a basis $B$ such that $C = C(e, B).$

**My thoughts:**

My idea for solving this question is that, given a circuit $\mathcal C,$ subtract from it an element $x,$ then $\mathcal{C} - x \in \mathcal{I}(M)$ which is the set of independent sets of the matroid M, then extend this set to a basis, say $\mathcal{B}$ (can any independent set in a matroid be extended to a basis always?) then add the $x$ back to this basis. But then how can I be sure that this constructed basis when $x$ is added to it will give me the circuit $\mathcal C$? Can anyone explain this to me or at least give me the correct way of proving this?

**EDIT:**

I am now reading this question [Circuits in a matroid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023924/circuits-in-a-matroid) to try to come up with a proof to my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have the right idea (I will use the notation as in the original problem statement):

- As you said, since $C$ is a circuit ("minimally dependent"), $C - e$ must be independent.
- There exists a basis $B \supseteq C - e$: A basis is by definition maximal independent sets. So, if $C - e$ isn't already a basis, it means that there is a strictly bigger, independent set $I$. So, by "iterating" this type of argument, you get a desired basis $B$ since $E$, the set on which our matroid $M$ lives, is finite.
- $B$ satisfies $C = C(e, B)$: Recall that $C(e,B)$ is defined to be the **unique circuit** in $B + e$, the so-called *fundamental-circuit of $e$ w.r.t. $B$*. See Corollary 1.2.6 for that. As $C \subseteq B + e$ and $C$ is a circuit, it must therefore already be $C(e,B)$ by uniqueness.

Comment: Do you recommend other easier books for studying Matroid Theory?

Comment: Frankly, I only took a seminar in Matroid Theory, so apart from Oxley, which we also used, I don't really have any other books to recommend. One conceptual thing that might be helpful at the beginning though is to keep the example of graphic matroids in mind, i.e. when making arguments in Matroid Theory, it is helpful to think them through "in the graph case" where circuits are cycles and independent sets are forests.